# How do i use awk command within a script to save permanent modifications

Tags: awk

How do I use `awk` command to make permanent modifications to a file? I have been using:

```
awk '/'"'"'test'"'"' =>./{c++}(c==2){sub("'"'"'test'"'"' =>.","'"'"'test'"'"' => '"'"'test1'"'"',")}1' testfile
```

I have been using the above command to make temporary changes that open the changes instantly. But I want to use it within the script file and make permanent changes to the file similar to `sed -i`.

Comment: I looked at it already. The responses were not accurate with respect to the question.

Comment: Regardless of the details of the Q, the first 2 answers have all you need to know about saving files inplace while using `awk`. When you search for `[awk] inplace`, there are 242 Q/A already. So this is a duplicate Q. Please read [help] before posting  more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Before this gets closed as a dup, lets at least clean up your code. This:

```
awk '/'"'"'test'"'"' =>./{c++}(c==2){sub("'"'"'test'"'"' =>.","'"'"'test'"'"' => '"'"'test1'"'"',")}1' testfile
```

is extremely hard to read. I assume all those `'"'"'`s are trying to get single quotes into the code. If so, to improve clarity and so it'd work if/when the script is stored in a file, use the octal representation `\047` for every single quote instead:

```
awk '/\047test\047 =>./{c++} (c==2){sub("\047test\047 =>.","\047test\047 => \047test1\047,")}1' testfile
```

Now use regexp delimiters for the regexp that's the first arg to `sub()`:

```
awk '/\047test\047 =>./{c++} (c==2){sub(/\047test\047 =>./,"\047test\047 => \047test1\047,")}1' testfile
```

There are several other possible improvements including using a backreference instead of hard-coding the original `sub()` string in the replacement and using `match()` so you don't need to test for the same regexp in the condition part of the script and then again in the `sub()` so something like this (with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match()) is probably all you need:

```
awk 'match($0,/(.*\047test\047 =>.)(.*)/,a){c++} c==2{$0=a[1] "\047test1\047" a[2]} 1' testfile
```

but without sample input output we can't know for sure - post a new question with sample input/output if you'd like more help.